# How to run local project on serveo

Tags: remote-access, remote-server

I want to run my local project on **serveo**
but its not working with my project URL.

local project url is:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test-project/
```

I am trying this command:

```
ssh -R 80:127.0.0.1/test-project:80 serveo.net
```

Error: `connect_to 127.0.0.1/test-project: unknown host (Name or service not known)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:80 serveo.net
```

then test it out with `http://<serveo generated subdomain>.serveo.net/test-project`